# Input tag - automatic file upload

Tags: javascript, html, input

Is it possible to load file automaticly with `<input>` tag?
This part of code loads any .csv file that you want, but since it will always be the same file, in same folder as this code, I would like it to load evertime this page loads.

```
<label>Load CSV file: </label>
<input type="file" id="fileInputCSV" />
var fileInputCSV = document.getElementById('fileInputCSV');
```

Comment: "Same folder as this code"?

Comment: "but since it will always be the same file" why is this required if the data is always the same?

Comment: Filename will be the same, but there will be some updates on data, done by some users in .xls files linked to the .csv file that needs to be uploaded. This will be an "offline" website, used by my collegues and placed on shared folder. Can it be done in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

To protect user's data, you can not do that in js.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in flash either.

Comment: @CharlieEgan Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Tomislav Paj for your question, you don't need a file input tag, you can hardcode the file path in your sever side code.

Answer (score 0):

> The value property of the input:file element is read-only, because of
>   security reasons.

[Source](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcgpgib.php)

This means it is not possible to do what you want with the CSV file.